# Swift Strings and [Character]

Tags: swift, string, indexing, character

I have this code:

```
let txt = "over 100MB+ of text..."
let tokenizedText = Array (txt)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression (pattern: "(?s)<tu>.*?</tu>")
let r = regex.matches (in: txt, range: NSRange (txt.startIndex..<txt.endIndex, in: txt))
for match in r {
    let befOfMatch = match.range.lowerBound
    let endOfMatch = match.range.lowerBound + match.range.length
    // check the result
    if tokenizedText[begOfMatch] != "<" {
        print ("error") // from time to time!!!!
    }
}
```

=> regex.matches produces integer ranges that are not always in sync with the characters array.
I know that UTF8 does not have a one-to-one correspondance between bytes and characters, but how to sync Strings and [Characters] ? I would need to:

-- retrieve the sequence of characters inside the matching sequences as [Character]

-- insert a tag (e.g. <found> ... </found>) around each matching sequence in the buffer (string)

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that NSRange it is based on UTF16 therefore the location of the resulting NSRange it is not necessarily the same as the character position in the array of characters (Not every character can be represented by a single byte). You need to convert the resulting NSRange to Range and check the original string using the lowerbound of the String Range:

```
let txt = "over 100MB+ of text... <tu>whatever</tu>"
let tokenizedText = Array (txt)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression (pattern: "(?s)<tu>.*?</tu>")
let r = regex.matches (in: txt, range: NSRange (txt.startIndex..<txt.endIndex, in: txt))
for match in r {
    if let range = Range(match.range, in: txt) {
        print (txt[range])
        if txt[range.lowerBound] == "<" {
            print(true)
        } else {
            print(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, but (1) all my parsers run on texts represented as [Character]... From txt and range, how do I compute the corresponding integer index in tokenizedText? (2) Reciprocally, Is there any O(1) way to compute the index in txt from an integer index in tokenizedText? Note that index(_:offsetBy:) is O(n), not O(1)...